# redirecting wmic command output to NUL

Tags: batch-file

I am using the wmic command to get the command Line  for a particular process if it is running. The scenario is to return the command line if the process is running else i want to redirect the output to NUL. 
In my case if the process is running i am good with this bit of code but if the process is not running(no spawning instance of java.exe) i get something like this in the console "No Instance(s) Available".
How to avoid this console output if java.exe is not running.
Below is the part of the code:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=7" %%f in ('wmic process where "name='java.exe'" get commandLine') do (
set v=%%f
goto function
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=7" %%f in ('wmic process where "name='java.exe'" get commandLine 2^>nul') do (
set v=%%f
goto function
)
```

This returns all error output of the program to nul, while still giving the normal output back. Note that you need to escape the `>` with a `^` because it is a special character.

This works because, as you probably noticed, `>nul` redirects normal output, but `2>nul` redirects only error output.

Comment: Perfect!! I was redirecting the output to NUL and thus for positive scenarios also i wasn't getting the normal output. Thanks a ton!! :)